# How to convert price column to integer in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I've tried so hard to convert the price column to integer. I keep seeing the error message.

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: You're missing the actual traceback; please copy and paste that (starting with `Traceback (most recent call last)`)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for posting good examples.
However, I suggest using lambda function for this:

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].apply(lambda x: int(x.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
```